# "Tail" a logstash server query

Tags: logstash

Assuming I have a logstash server chocked full of logs being loaded regularly, is there a reasonably elegant way that I can tail the results of a continuously executing query on the logstash server and show this in a terminal window

e.g

`some-special-logstash-command.sh | egrep -v "(searchword1|searchword2)"`

the idea being that the command pipes stuff out of logstash and to my grep query that filters and shows me  the filtered output for.

.. of course if there is a logstash command that can do the grep piece for me as well, then that works too :)

motivation for doing this, is that assuming all of my events from my estate is being loaded into logstash, then would be nice to have a terminal window with a continuous tail of interesting events as they occur scrolling past the screen.

-Ace

Comment: Your events are being stored in elasticsearch, I presume?

Comment: yup - should have mentioned that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Include configuration in your `logstash` collector to do the [`grep`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/grep) work and to output to [`stdout`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/outputs/stdout). This is an example using a [`file`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/inputs/file) input:

```
input {
  file {
    add_field => ... # hash (optional), default: {}
    codec => ... # codec (optional), default: "plain"
    discover_interval => ... # number (optional), default: 15
    exclude => ... # array (optional)
    path => ... # array (required)
    sincedb_path => ... # string (optional)
    sincedb_write_interval => ... # number (optional), default: 15
    start_position => ... # string, one of ["beginning", "end"] (optional), default: "end"
    stat_interval => ... # number (optional), default: 1
    tags => ... # array (optional)
    type => ... # string (optional)
  }
}
filter {
  grep {
    add_field => ... # hash (optional), default: {}
    add_tag => ... # array (optional), default: []
    drop => ... # boolean (optional), default: true
    ignore_case => ... # boolean (optional), default: false
    match => ... # hash (optional), default: {}
    negate => ... # boolean (optional), default: false
    remove_field => ... # array (optional), default: []
    remove_tag => ... # array (optional), default: []
  }
}
output {
  stdout {}
}
```